# jqgrid drag and drop files into grid for upload

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid that I list files in after they are uploaded. It works fine but its not the best user experience. There is a drag and drop box they move the files into.

Thats the drag and drop box.

```
<div id="filedragbox"> 
                                    <div>
                                        <div id="filedrag"><label for="fileselect" >Files to upload:</label><input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple"/>or drop files here</div>
                                    </div>
```

This is the listener code

```
filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
    filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
    filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);

// file drag hover
function FileDragHover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
}


// file selection
function FileSelectHandler(e) {

    // cancel event and hover styling
    FileDragHover(e);

    // fetch FileList object
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    // process all File objects
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        ParseFile(f);
        UploadFile(f);
    }
}
```

However I'm wondering if it's possible to do drag and drop files into jqgrid for uploading files. using the same idea. That the user can drag and drop a file into the grid space that then fires the file upload.

If not I can keep it the way I have it now. I think it would just be nicer for the user to drag directly into the grid

Comment: Just an update for anyone interested in this.

I have tried the jqgrid on drop event
`ondrop: function (ev, ui, getdata) {alert("here");},`

no joy.

I have also just created a test table with a single row and cell. I can add the 

event listeners as follows
`test.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
test.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
test.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);`

and i can drag and drop a file into that table. I will keep working to try and find a way to make this work

Comment: You may have realized this by now, but please stop trying to ping specific users in your questions. Adding `@oleg` has no effect, users cannot be notified that way, and questions are not allowed be addressed to specific users here.